# Software Updater ignores frequency setting

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

Software Updater shows every day with new updates.
But in System settings -> Software & Updates -> Updates (tab) -> Automatically check for updates (dropdown list) set to "Every two weeks".

And there is nothing in "Startup Applications" app.

Is it a bug or I'm doing some thing wrong?

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Did you install all the updates?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, i did.